# Automapper not mapping entities that are newly added in Entity Framework 4.1 context

Tags: entity-framework-4, automapper

I am lazy loading my entities and when I make an initial call to pull a list of entities I am seeing the System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies....type. Which is fine and my entities map to my DTOs just fine. The issue I am having is that when I add a new item to my context it is being pulled fromt he context and not the database. So, I see the list being pulled back with the System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies types and an my new item taht is the actual type of object.

So, for example I may have a list like this:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contact...
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contact...
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Contact...
MyNameSpace.Contact
```

I created a custom type converter and noticed that the DynamicProxy types have a source value, but the MyNameSpace.Contact does not have a source value. So, it is not getting mapped in my type converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `CreateObject/Create` method in your ObjectSet/DbSet when you are creating the entity without using the constructor.

```
var newContact = context.Contacts.Create();
context.Contacts.Add(newContact);
```

The returned object is a proxy that supports lazy loading.

Comment: that doesn't really help me in my situation because of my architecture. I have a repository and Unit Of Work and they way I am creating entities is different.

Comment: @DDiVita Sorry you need to add the new entity to the `ObjectSet/DbSet` first to get the lazy loading functionality. Updated my answer.

Comment: actually, this didn't work. I ended up having to call: context.Entry(entity).Reference(expression).Load(); and the properties would be loaded all the time.

Comment: @ddivita Is that an eager load? If so, it's not really a solution to the original question (not saying that you claim it is)